Middleware redirects not working in NextJS app based routing
I am experiencing an issue with the middleware. I need to route the user based on their role, but the middleware is not able to route properly. Here's the explanation:
I have two roles in my app, manager and staff, and a user can have either of these roles in their respective org.
When the user changes the org using a dropdown in the UI, the middleware is supposed to detect the new selected org and route the user to the corresponding URL. I've written the following logic for this:
if (orgRole === 'manager' && request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/staff')) {
      const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
      url.pathname = `${orgShortId}/dashboard/manager/app`
      return NextResponse.redirect(url, { status: 303 })
    }

    if (orgRole === 'staff' && request.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/manager')) {
      const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
      url.pathname = `${orgShortId}/dashboard/staff/app`
      return NextResponse.redirect(url, { status: 303 })
    }

However, the issue I'm facing is that the app is not getting routed to the URL as expected; it remains unchanged.

It looks solid, even tho you might not need to clone the nextUrl and set the pathname on that instance. Have you confirmed that the orgRole is what you expect (console/logger statement)?

@robbash yes it is same as I want

You could try to put revalidatePath('/', 'layout') into your root layout. It will cause the cache to be invalidated on every request so do not use in prod but to debug it might help. If it works that way you need to look into your cache management. Be careful with cross-session cache use.
